# State invalidation update selectors

Tags: ngxs

Need to have selectors update when action handler does not update model due to invalid data.

Looking for a strategy to handle actions that would invalidate state so are dismissed. Components often fire actions with data and the state action handler determines invalid so does not update state with invalid data. However, without the update, selectors do not fire so component is left in invalid state. Memoization is great but need a mechanism to force a selector update so that components will bind correctly.

Looked at binding to the entire state, double updates, wrapping values in complex objects but all seem like hacks to a common cross cutting concern. Any patterns out there i might be missing.

Comment: Please include code that illustrates what you are describing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If the state doesn't update/change, the selectors don't fire because the state object is still the same. Can't you dispatch some InvalidStateAction in the state and respond to that using an action handler? https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/action-handlers